# AngularJS - Unknown Provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource, angularjs-module

I'm trying to create a small note-taking application using AngularJS, but I stumbled at the very beginning. Here's my .js file:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngResource']);

app.factory("note", ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource("/api/notes/:id", {id:'@id'}, {
        query: {method: "GET", isArray: true}});
        }
    ]
);

app.controller("NotesController", function($scope, $note){
    console.log("I am being constructed");
    $scope.notes = $note.query();
});
```

And here's the html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jotted</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <link href='style/main.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" >
    <div ng-controller="NotesController">
        <div ng-repeat="note in notes">
            {{note.title}}
        </div>          
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried adding

```
NotesController.$inject("$scope", "Note");
```

but it only gave ma an error saying that NotesController does not have a method named "$inject".

Nothing is displayed and the browser returns an error: "Error: Unknown provider: $noteProvider <- $note". Certainly I am missing something obvious, but I can't put my finger on it. Where does the problem lie?

Comment: Include the ngResource JS file befor the controllers.js file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the $ Sign before your $note. The dollar Sign is only a convention of the Framework to identify internal Providers,... .

For example try:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngResource']);

app.factory("note", ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource("/api/notes/:id", {id:'@id'}, {
        query: {method: "GET", isArray: true}});
        }
    ]
);

app.controller("NotesController", function($scope, note){
    console.log("I am being constructed");
    $scope.notes = note.query();
});
```

Comment: @groovy354, try to stay consistent in your code, you used the min-safe synthax for the service, why not using it for the controller ?

`app.controller("NotesController", ["$scope", "note", function($scope, note) { ... }]);`